# Paypal Button Code to Auto Redirect after payment

Tags: paypal

In my paypal button, I have the return and cancel_return variable with their urls. When a payment is complete and a user wants to return to the site, they will have to click the link.

I read in different places that for me to enable auto redirect, I will need to go to Profile, Website Payments Payments Preferences, Auto Return.

The problem is that when I go to Profile, I cannot find Website Payments Payments Preferences, so I would like to find out how this can be done programmatically on the button.

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the type of account you have where it shows up or even shows up at all. I think that you need to be at lease a Premier or a Business for those profile options to show up. Once you are that type of user you will find "Website Payments Preferences" section and on that screen you will find the first option marked as "Auto Return for Website Payments". THere is a ON / OFF option.

Answer (score 7):

Took me a while to find it but for my real account it was not where the documentation said it was or where it was in the Sandbox. I found it under:

My Account > Profile > My Selling Tools

Then click on "Update" link under:

Selling Online > Website Preferences

Comment: Thx..looking for this solution