# Paypal never redirects to my website after transaction

Tags: asp.net, paypal, transactions

I have used Paypal integration in my asp.net application and want Paypal to redirect back to my specified page that I have given in its url:

```
//Success return page url
        redirecturl += "&return=" +
          ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessURL"].ToString();

        //Failed return page url
        redirecturl += "&cancel_return=" +
          ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedURL"].ToString();

        Response.Redirect(redirecturl);
```

But it never returns back to my website, instead it just shows "Thanks for your order" with Paypal url in address bar.
[image]

What should I do to force it return to my website's page after completing the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit the return URL when you are submitting the data to paypal. You can not just use Response.Redirect as for that point, it is already in Paypal's site, so your asp script will not be executed. Specify the return_url parameter when sending the request to Paypal. For more information about the parameters, refer to : https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

Comment: I think the OP is creating the return URL parameter correctly.  It looks like the OP is doing something similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19957382/340045).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4472646/340045), apparently you can set an Auto Redirect option on your PayPal profile.  However, this will depend on the type of account you have.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I do [this](http://blogandretire.com/blog/2012/02/redirect-buyers-to-your-site-after.html) and every thing works fine.

from [Blog](http://blogandretire.com/blog/2012/02/redirect-buyers-to-your-site-after.html)

> Login to your PayPal account.
>
> Hover your mouse over Profile, then scroll down and click on More Options.
>
> On the right-hand side, click My selling tools
>
> Under Selling online, go down to Website Preferences and click Update (on left-hand side).
>
> Under “Auto Return for Website Payments,” click the option for Auto Return to “On”
>
> Next, type in the default url you wish to lead your customers to, if you don’t specify a url in your paypal button code. (However, no matter what, PayPal will redirect your customers back to PayPal if you don’t add the below html code to your finished button code. You have to have auto return On and you also have to add the code below to your paypal button code.)
>
> Go down to the bottom of the page and click “Save”.

See more at: http://blogandretire.com/blog/2012/02/redirect-buyers-to-your-site-after.html